# Leafs turn yellow on little lemon tree

Tags: diagnosis, lemons

I planted a lemon seed and I got a "tiny" lemon tree. I have it in very little soil so it doesn't grow too big but (surprisingly) it is in the same minuscule  state for like a year now. I wasn't really worried about it since it looked healthy enough. Last week I noticed that the leafs turned yellow.

More info:

- The soil is like 5cm deep
- The location is the Netherlands
- There is also some grass in the same pot

[image]

Comment: Try to transplant it into a bigger pot (with drainage holes), with fresh potting soil. Put it in a sunny spot and water it daily for the rest of the summer.

Comment: What it is the pH of the soil? If you have hard water, pH will increases, and so lemon have difficulties to grow. Try using some acid soil (or put some lemon juice in the soil). Fertilizer could also be a factor (and wrong pH makes assimilation of nutrients a lot more difficult).